# Ubuntu 20.10 crashed and is now stuck in reboot loop: initramsfs: unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, grubrescue, initramfs

I was working on a Libre Office Document, then suddenly my Ubuntu 20.10 (updated from 20.04) which is installed on a Laptop just crashed. I can still see the grub menu but now I'm unable to boot, it is stuck in a reboot loop after grub. The only thing it shows for a second is:

```
initramsfs: unpacking failed: Decoding failed
```

Sometimes there's also:

```
initramsfs: unpacking failed: Decoding failed
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: Clearing orphaned inode 11810182 (uuid...
/dev/sda2: Clearing orphaned inode 11815886 (uuid...
/dev/sda2: Clearing orphaned inode 11815874 (uuid...
/dev/sda2: clean, 977045/15237120 files, ...
```

Then black screen, power turns off and reboot.

The only thing I changed on this machine is upgrading the RAM like 2 weeks ago but with no issues until today.

I tried to boot in recovery mode from grub, but same problem. I've never had this issue before. What should I try next?

**EDIT 1:**

- I tried booting an Ubuntu live-usb. Same behavior as stated above.
- Then I thought I try a Windows 10 usb which I have laying around. Now it booted into the installation menu.
- Then I switched back to the Ubuntu live-usb from before and now it boots as expected.
- Finally I tried my Ubuntu installation on my laptop. It does magically work again like before without issues..

This seems odd to me.

Comment: The messages displayed aren't a problem. I guess that upgrading the ram is causing a problem. Is the ram compatible with your motherboard? Installing additional ram causes extra power-consumption and will raise the temperature. If the cooling-system is not ok, the computer will overheat and shutdown randomly. Are you still able to boot from a live-usb?

Comment: Hello! I would start the computer with a live usb stick and check the smart status of your hard drive. If it is okay, the next step should be a filesystem check + repair (fsck?) and repair grub.

Comment: I updated the question, it works again but I have no clue why exactly booting windows helped. I'm not sure about a RAM issue, but I will test it with memtest. I used it quiet heavily the last 2 weeks without any issues (Docker, Virtualbox, etc). It is compatible with the mobo.